# Multiple Queries reflected on URL React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Normally, my query reflects on the URL.

For example, I need to search for the word 'StackOverflow'. My URL would be https//mysite.com/?keyword=stackoverflow

However, on the same page, I have two different search bars and users search for different keywords. How can I handle it on the same URL?

Note the backend params in two cases is the same 'keyword'

Could you suggest me a solution? Thank you in advanced

Comment: Reading the API documentation would help better. If the query param keyword is an array/List then it can be achieved by simply like https//mysite.com/?keyword=stackoverflow,SomethingElse

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible for you to use two parameters? As in website.com?keyword1=test&keyword2=test2

Comment: I am thinking of this solution. Right now my work flow is that I just convert the url to query params and send it to the backend. If I use two prams, it is hard to change my already work flow because this project is huge. Thank for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but not recommended.

```
// example.
// keyword={keyword1}@@@{keyword2}
// @@@ <--- splitter. choose yourself!

?keyword=stackoverflow@@@google
const queryStrings = window.location.search.split("&");
const keywordQuery = queryStrings.filter((q) => q.includes("keyword") > -1)[0];
const [keyword1, keyword2] = keywordQuery.replace("keyword=", "").split("@@@");
```

If you use this, you be care for `@@@`. bacuase You can't search `@@@`!!!